# When is the MGF = $[^{-}]$ for A random variable X?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, expected-value, moment-generating-functions

I want to compute the moment generating function of a random variable X that has a PDF defined only for $x\ge 0$.
I have found some papers that use the following definitions for the MGF:
\begin{equation}
\text{MGF}_X(s)=\mathbb{E}(e^{-sX})=\int_0^\inf e^{-sx}f(x)dx
\end{equation}

How is this minus sign came ?? By definition, the MGF is expressed as $\mathbb{E}(e^{sX})$, meaning without a minus.
Are they some conditions on X such that MGF$_X =\mathbb{E}(e^{-sX})$ becomes correct and valid ?

If so, I want to apply the lotus principle on the minus form as it makes it easier to bound and integrate. Any suggestions ??

Comment: That isn't the moment generating function, though it is the laplace transform of a probability measure $\mu$ supported on $\mathbb R_+$

Comment: The PDF f(x) of X is defined only for positive values of x. The MGF is defined as expectation of $e^(sX)$. Some references such as https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/7145607 mention the MGF with minus.

Comment: Well, you can call it whatever you want. From a practical viewpoint, the Laplace transform and moment generating function do the same thing, $C^\infty$ function which characterizes the distribution. Moreover, if laplace transforms converge pointwise to a function which is right continuous at 0, then one has weak convergence.

Comment: Sorry I do not understand the link with Laplace. can you elaborate ? and how does this links to this minus in the formula ? I am very confused. I just want to compute the MGF and saw formulas with minus.

Comment: It's just a matter of convention. Similarly; the characteristic function is sometimes called $\Bbb E[e^{isX}]$ or sometimes it is $\Bbb E[e^{-isX}]$. It doesn't actually *matter*, you just need to be clear when reading/writing a text what your convention is. The link with "Laplace" is that the *usual* naming system has $\Bbb E[e^{-sX}]$ called the *Laplace transform* rather than the MGF. But different people will say different things

Comment: The laplace transform of a probability measure $\mu$ supported on $\mathbb R_+$ is defined by $\mathcal L_\mu (s) = \int_0^\infty e^{-sx}\mu(dx)$ for $s\geq 0$. The Laplace transform, analogous to the Fourier transform, completely characterizes such measures and an analogous Levy’s continuity theorem holds. In this sense, Laplace transform plays the same role as MGF. Though nobody (except say the authors of the paper you are reading) calls the laplace transform the MGF.

Comment: It should be noted that the Laplace transform may be preferred over the MGF, the former always exists, the latter may fail to exist.

Comment: Thank you for your precisions. Just to understand more this nuance. The Q function has an expression that involves the MGF. is that also possible to replace with Laplace transform since both are somehow similar ?